# How to recharge the page on ajax redirection

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, authorize.net

I am using AuthorizeAttribute to manage Session in my ASP MVC 3 application. But I have problems with how the login page is displayed when the session is dead. I believe it's because the page is not recharged. So how can I oblige the page to be recharged if the session is over on each AJAX request ?

Thanks.

EDIT :

I use authorization like this

```
[Authorize]
public class MySettingsController : Controller
{
  //my code here
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Via javascript:

```
location.reload()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but my question is how to execute this code on each ajax request after testing if the user is logged in. Should I put something in the global.asax file ?

Comment: No, I use something like this var request = $.ajax({
        url: $('#' + formId).attr("action"),
        type: 'post',
        data: $('#' + formId).serialize()

    });

Comment: Authorize attribute should return HTTP 401 response code when the user is not logged in, with jQuery you can handle such responses: $.ajaxSetup({
error: function(xhr, status, err) {
if (xhr.status == 401)
window.location.reload();
}
});

Comment: I did that, but it does not work. I put an alert message inside the function, it's never displayed. I updated the question, I use authorize like shown above.